# Having problem targeting the text inside li

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem to find a selector for the text inside my "li" to target with JavaScript. The problem is that I have a nested "span" element with two icons in my "li". That gives me a problem just to "li" to target it, since, it also covers the "span" with icons. What I am trying to do is add {text-decoration: 'line-through'} when the 'check' icon is clicked. and remove the text, when 'trash'icon is clicked. As I said, my problem is targeting the text within the "li" .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="list-container">
        <h1>Task List</h1>
        <form id="addTask">
          <input type="text" id="InputText" placeholder="Enter your task..." />
        </form>
        <div class="task-list">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span id="iconPkg"
                ><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i
              ></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn">Clear List</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
const inputText = document.querySelector("#InputText");
const addTask = document.querySelector("#addTask");
const taskList = document.querySelector(".task-list");
const iconPkg = document.querySelector("#iconPkg");
const crossOut = document.querySelector(".fa-check");
const deleteItem = document.querySelector(".fa-trash-alt");
let LIText = document.querySelector(".task-list > ul > li:first-child");

addTask.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  taskList.innerHTML += `
  <div class="task-list">
  <ul>
    <li>${inputText.value}
      <span
        ><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i
      ></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  `;
  iconPkg.removeAttribute("display");
  inputText.value = "";
});

crossOut.addEventListener("click", () => {
  LIText.style.textDecoration = "lineThrough";
});
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to reduce the code example to just the applicable parts that aren't working, will help people answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can only select elements and pseudo-elements/classes. Therefore you must wrap it in an element. A `span` element should do the trick in this case:

```js
const inputText = document.querySelector("#InputText");
const addTask = document.querySelector("#addTask");
const taskList = document.querySelector(".task-list");
const iconPkg = document.querySelector("#iconPkg");
const crossOut = document.querySelector(".fa-check");
const deleteItem = document.querySelector(".fa-trash-alt");
let LIText = document.querySelector(".task-list > ul > li > span");

addTask.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  taskList.innerHTML += `
  <div class="task-list">
  <ul>
    <li><span>${inputText.value}</span>
      <span
        ><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i
      ></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  `;
  iconPkg.removeAttribute("display");
  inputText.value = "";
});

crossOut.addEventListener("click", () => {
  LIText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="list-container">
        <h1>Task List</h1>
        <form id="addTask">
          <input type="text" id="InputText" placeholder="Enter your task..." />
        </form>
        <div class="task-list">
          <ul>
            <li><span>Some text</span>
              <span id="iconPkg"
                ><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i
              ></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn">Clear List</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Spectric! I did what you suggested. It definitely made the code more sound and easier to read by others, but it didn't do the trick. Still no response when clicked. Not even an error. And that makes it more difficult.

Comment: @bdara Hmmm... in the code snippet `text-decoration:underline` is applied when I click on the checkmark. Do you want this to happen on newly created items in the list too?